# jq add character before and after every row JSON

Tags: json, set, transform, jq, strip

I want print "[]" in every row with jq to make a big file json proof

I have:

```
{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}
{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}
{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}
{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}
```

What i want:

```
[[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]
[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]
[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]
[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]]
```

Now i can push the json line by line to a program.

Comment: The output shown is _not_ a valid JSON. Update your question to reflect the actual. Did you mean to show an array of arrays?

Comment: The input is a nice stream of JSON objects.  The output you indicate you want is not valid JSON, so it's hard to see why you describe it as "json proof".  If you want to convert a stream of JSON entities to a single JSON array, which would make sense, you can just run `jq -s .`.  There is hopefully no good reason to do anything more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you input are just plain objects:
Use `--slurp` to create a single array, then use `map([ . ])` to wrap each object in his own array

```
jq --slurp --compact-output 'map([ . ])'
[[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}],[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}], ...
```

[JqPlay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ehGkw8oxBsw)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file contains a stream of stand-alone JSON objects, the filter is simply `[.]`. The filter will be applied to each input object.

```
jq -c '[.]' file.json
```

Output:

```json
[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]
[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]
[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]
[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]
```

To wrap everything in one big array:

```
jq -s . file.json
# or:
jq -s <file.json
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "test": "index",
    "test2": "fdsdfs",
    "test3": "dfs0D0WOQAA3"
  },
  {
    "test": "index",
    "test2": "fdsdfs",
    "test3": "dfs0D0WOQAA3"
  },
  {
    "test": "index",
    "test2": "fdsdfs",
    "test3": "dfs0D0WOQAA3"
  },
  {
    "test": "index",
    "test2": "fdsdfs",
    "test3": "dfs0D0WOQAA3"
  }
]
```

And to wrap each single item in an array and all arrays in a top-level array:

```
jq 'map([.])' file.json
```

Output:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "test": "index",
      "test2": "fdsdfs",
      "test3": "dfs0D0WOQAA3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "test": "index",
      "test2": "fdsdfs",
      "test3": "dfs0D0WOQAA3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "test": "index",
      "test2": "fdsdfs",
      "test3": "dfs0D0WOQAA3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "test": "index",
      "test2": "fdsdfs",
      "test3": "dfs0D0WOQAA3"
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just forgot to put the commas in your otherwise valid JSON output, in which case you can find reasonable answers elsewhere on this page.

If not, and your desired output is accurate as shown, one way to solve it with jq is to read in the lines as raw text, prepend and append to certain lines as you see fit, and output again as raw text:

```bash
jq -Rnr '[inputs] | (first, .[]) |= "[" + . | (last, .[]) += "]" | .[]'
```

```json
[[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]
[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]
[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]
[{"test":"index","test2":"fdsdfs","test3":"dfs0D0WOQAA3"}]]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pqNTQTs8o6-)

But, to be fair, you actually don't need a JSON processor if it is just plain text being manipulated. Using `sed` or `awk` would be more reasonable choices here.